# How to pause a specific string after it has been sent from client to server in java?

Tags: java, sockets

I have done a small application that search for Bluetooth devices and gets its Bluetooth address. After getting the Bluetooth address the application will check in a text file (this file contain a number of Bluetooth addresses) if the discovered Bluetooth address matches any of the ones in the text file then send that address to the server (this process will repeated many times because it is a loop).  Note: the Bluetooth address is stored in a String.
So, what I want is to pause that Bluetooth address from sending to the server for a period of time while keeping the searching and sending process continues working.
Any ideas how can I do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an involved question, but it sounds like what you need is a multi-threaded solution:

1. Thread(s) to search
2. Thread(s) to send to server (with delay, etc)

Have a look at [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and using [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) tasks to help with the threading.

Also consider a [Producer Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern implemented using a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to [decouple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decouple#Software_Development) searching from sending - search results are put on the queue and the sender pulls them off the queue, but each can process independently.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be to use java.util.Timer: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html.